# runtime: UI API called from background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState] must be used from main thread only

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

Mac System: 10.12.6
SDK: Xcode 9.0
Deployment Target: iOS 9.0

I'm a pretty new developer, but I persue No Warning in my code.

After I upgrade my Xcode to 9, my code show some warnings not exist before. The most misrable is runtime warning shows below, I know it's from Main Thread Check, and I can make it diappear by setting. But i wonder how to fixed it, I have make all my change UI code in the main thread, just like :

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    });
```

Here is my screenshots about warnings and Xcode logs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do u checked the above code without the dispatch_async block ?

Comment: Yes ,and the result is the same.

Comment: can you show more code above and below of this piece of code

Comment: Here is one of my viewDidLoad, I've try put change BarStyle and color code in dispatch_async(), but it's not work(Warning sitll there). I think this is not right way to fix the problem.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to search for `applicationState` in the project to get all places where this issue could refer to. But I'm facing the exact same problem and I didn't find it anywhere in my code. I suspect it comes from an external library, but not sure.

Comment: I think this problem still needs some time to fix by senior programmer.

Comment: Do you use any third-party libraries? Check if the problem is not caused by some of those libraries / frameworks. You may have those installed via Cocoapods, Carthage etc.

Comment: I use Cocoapods installed some third libraries, but how can I find which code cause the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating your pod should solve the issue. I had the same warning prior updating my google map pod.

updating google map pod

[image]